# Avoid passing the same argument to multiple methods in the same class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can I run multiple methods, with one data in ruby on rails, here my example:

In my Controller:

```
def update
 item = Content::Video.find(params[:video_id])
 data = Data.new(params[:data])
 video_name = item.content
  #example: item,data and video_name != nil

 update_content(data)
 update_resouce_item(data, item)
 update_video_content(data, item, video_name)
end

private
def update_content(data)
.....
end

def update_resouce_item(data, item)
....
end

def update_video_content(data, item, video_name)
....
end
```

Normally, to run these methods: update_content, update_resouce_item, update_video_content, I must call "data" three times for each methods, but I just want to call "data" one time and run all methods with it.Can I do that in ruby on rails? please! tell me:)

Comment: What's your `data`? Is it a proc?

Comment: Here my data: data = Data.new(params[:data]), it just a normal data, in my app it is an array

Comment: So I don't understand what you mean by "I must call >>data<< three times for each method".

Comment: Sorry, if my English so bad. Here is how I call "data": 
 update_content(data) -- one time
 update_resouce_item(data, item) -- two times
 update_video_content(data, item, video_name) -- three times

Comment: what do you mean one time, two times, three times, .. it seems like you created the object just once and used it three times, nothing is wrong with that..

Comment: No, no! nothing wrong with that, I just want to know if there is any way to use "data" one time for all method like this : call "data" run  (update_content, update_resouce_item(item), update_video_content(item,video_name))

Answer (score 0):

You can use instance variables to share a variable within the same controller:

```
def update
 item = Content::Video.find(params[:video_id])
 @data = Data.new(params[:data])
 video_name = item.content
  #example: item,data and video_name != nil

 update_content(data)
 update_resouce_item(item)
 update_video_content(item, video_name)
end

private
def update_content()
    @data # data is available as @data
end

def update_resouce_item(item)
    @data # data is available as @data
end

def update_video_content(item, video_name)
    @data # data is available as @data
end
```

Rails also exports instance vars from the controller to your views and helpers.

Although there is nothing wrong with passing variables as arguments and this more "functional" style often has a lot of merits due to its explicit nature.

In rails `before_action` filters are often used to setup variables that are shared by several actions.

```
before_action :set_data

def set_data
    @data = Data.find(params[:id])
end
```